# How to check for '3 words' in a input cobol variable of length 10, if found skip record?

Tags: cobol, mainframe

INPUT: WS-Variable contains '345xABCx12'

Code: IF WS-Variable string contains 'ABC' Display ' SKIP!!!' Else Perform something.

```
If variable contains 'abc'
  display skipped
else
  process-para
end if.
```

Answer (score 2):

You are looking for the [INSPECT](http://publibfp.boulder.ibm.com/cgi-bin/bookmgr/BOOKS/IGY3LR31/6.2.21?DT=20060329140556) verb... Try something like...

```
   IDENTIFICATION DIVISION.
   PROGRAM-ID. EXAMPLE.
   DATA DIVISION.
   WORKING-STORAGE SECTION.
   01  TESTDATA  PIC X(50).
   01  COUNTER   PIC 9(4).
   PROCEDURE DIVISION.
       MOVE '12345XXABCXX12345' TO TESTDATA
       MOVE ZERO TO COUNTER
       INSPECT TESTDATA TALLYING COUNTER FOR ALL 'ABC'
       IF COUNTER > 0
          DISPLAY 'SKIP! ' TESTDATA
       ELSE
          DISPLAY 'DONT SKIP ' TESTDATA
       END-IF
       MOVE '12345XXZZZXX12345' TO TESTDATA
       MOVE ZERO TO COUNTER
       INSPECT TESTDATA TALLYING COUNTER FOR ALL 'ABC'
       IF COUNTER > 0
          DISPLAY 'SKIP! ' TESTDATA
       ELSE
          DISPLAY 'DONT SKIP ' TESTDATA
       END-IF
       GOBACK
       .
```

Comment: @AgentMahone you are new, so probably don't know about Upvotes and Accepting. Have a little search around, it is the way we get an evaluation beyond your comments.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try something like:?

```
If variable equal to 'abc'
  display "skipped"
else
  perform process-para
end-if
```

This would assume variable is defined as PIC XXX or X(3).

If that does not suit, please update your question with a fuller description, some sample input, expected output and what you have tried.

Now it turns out you are looking for 'abc' at a variable location within a piece of data.

There are several ways to do it.

Easiest is

```
INSPECT field-you-want-to-look-at 
  TALLYING a-count 
  FOR ALL value-you-want-to-search-for
```

a-count can be defined as BINARY PIC 9(4). value-you-want-to-search-for as PIC XXX VALUE 'abc'.

MOVE ZERO TO a-count before the INSPECT.

After the INSPECT you can test a-count which will tell you how many occurences of value-you-want-to-search-for there are in field-you-want-to-look-at.

The reason to use a data-definition (PIC XXX) instead of a literal ('abc') is for ease of maintenance and understanding. There may be more than one place where 'abc' is required in the program, and it may mean the same thing in both places, or one thing in one place and something else in another. With a data-name from the definition you can describe what 'abc' means in each instance. If the value of 'abc' (or one of the 'abc's) needs to change, there is only one place it needs to be changed - in the working-storage.

If (and assuming Enterprise COBOL on the Mainframe due to the COOLGEN reference) you use compiler option OPT(STD) or OPT(FULL) a data-name which is referenced but is never the "target" of anything, ie it has a constant value, is treated as a constant. So you get a named constant as well.

```
INSPECT FLIGHTPLAN-REFERENCE 
  TALLYING NO-OF-ENTRIES-TO-EU-AIRSPACE
  FOR ALL EU-FLIGHTPLAN-CODE
```

Is much more easy to understand than

```
INSPECT VAR1 TALLYING A-COUNT FOR ALL 'abc'
```

Comment: No Bill.. Actually Variable contains 'abc'
EX Input is:  '123xyz123abc111'
Now this contain abc
Variable = 'abc' wont help

Comment: THANKS BILLY .. THAT SHUD WORK WELL

Comment: Please still edit your original question. I have already flagged the duplicate for Moderator attention.

Comment: Hi Billy ... why we need to define the PIC XXX VALUE 'abc'.??
it will be like INSPECT WS-CONTACT TALLYING  TALLY-CNT FOR ALL 'ABC'
...WHY WE NEED TO MAKE A VARIABLE TO STORE THE 'ABC' ?

Comment: DELETED THAT 2ND QUESTION